# Postfix: Recieve emails in Mailbox in /var/spool/mail

Tags: postfix, email-server, centos7

I have a vps in contabo I installed a postfix mail server, OS Centos 7, but now postfix use an structure to save the emails and the mailbox in folders structures in a Maildir folder, but i dont need that: for example:

```
/home/servername/Maildir/curr/
```

And in that location you can find several files, each file for each email. I dont need that.

I need a traditional mailbox in a single file mailbox located in /var/spool/mail/myEmailAccount.

¿Its there a way that I can fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and look for the line starting `home_mailbox=`.

For mail to be delivered as you described, it is probably set to `home_mailbox=Maildir/`.  Comment out this line by putting `#` at the start, then `postfix reload`.

The default mailbox file is `/var/spool/mail/user`, so not having any `home_mailbox` line should give your desired result.

Comment: And how can I create a new mailbox that its located in /var/spool/mail to have several mailbox in that location.

Comment: When a user receives new mail, the `/var/spool/mail/user` file should be created automatically for them.  No need to create it explicitly.

Comment: But how should a send a mail to that user?

Comment: I sended several to test but nothing happened

Comment: It works for me. Though I prefer emails in separate files - so I'll have to reconfigure.